# Is the Stripe API test key limited to certain features?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments, api-key

I'm building an ecommerce application using Stripe for the first time.  I'm making a GET request to the endpoint `/v1/products` using either Insomnia or the Stripe npm package to get my complete product data which will then populate the catalogue page.

My question is whether there is limited functionality on the test secret key Stripe provides? As when I use it the return data is an empty array, compared with the live api key which returns the array populated with products.

This:

```
import Stripe from 'stripe';
const stripe = Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_TEST_SECRET_KEY);

stripe.products.list()
  .then(console.log);
```

Returns this:

```
{
"object": "list",
"data": [],
"has_more": false,
"url": "/v1/products"
}
```

Whereas swapping `STRIPE_TEST_SECRET_KEY` for `STRIPE_LIVE_SECRET_KEY` returns this:

```
{
"object": "list",
"data": [
    {
        "id": "tower",
        "object": "product",
        "active": true,
        "attributes": [
            "height",
            "colour",
            "waterproof"
        ],
        "caption": "Tower",
        "created": 1520612842,
        "deactivate_on": [],
        "description": null,
        "images": [],
        "livemode": true,
        "metadata": {},
        "name": "Tower",
        "package_dimensions": {
            "height": 20.0,
            "length": 20.0,
            "weight": 700.0,
            "width": 80.0
        },
        "shippable": true,
        "skus": {
            "object": "list",
            "data": [
                {
                    "id": "t001",
                    "object": "sku",
                    "active": true,
                    "attributes": {
                        "height": "1600",
                        "colour": "White",
                        "waterproof": "False"
                    },
                    "created": 1520612987,
                    "currency": "gbp",
                    "inventory": {
                        "quantity": 10,
                        "type": "finite",
                        "value": null
                    },
                    "livemode": true,
                    "metadata": {},
                    "package_dimensions": {
                        "height": 20.0,
                        "length": 20.0,
                        "weight": 700.0,
                        "width": 80.0
                    },
                    "price": 90000,
                    "product": "tower",
                    "updated": 1520674446
                },
                {
                    "id": "t002",
                    "object": "sku",
                    "active": true,
                    "attributes": {
                        "height": "1600",
                        "colour": "White",
                        "waterproof": "True"
                    },
                    "created": 1520613174,
                    "currency": "gbp",
                    "image": null,
                    "inventory": {
                        "quantity": 10,
                        "type": "finite",
                        "value": null
                    },
                    "livemode": true,
                    "metadata": {},
                    "package_dimensions": {
                        "height": 20.0,
                        "length": 20.0,
                        "weight": 700.0,
                        "width": 80.0
                    },
                    "price": 110000,
                    "product": "tower",
                    "updated": 1520613174
                }
            ],
            "has_more": false,
            "total_count": 8,
            "url": "/v1/skus?product=tower&active=true"
        },
        "type": "good",
        "updated": 1520674071,
        "url": null
    }
],
"has_more": false,
"url": "/v1/products"
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not Stripe customer support](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746/2988).

Comment: Hi Jörg, the post you linked on customer support questions says asking about using company's APIs is acceptable. In any case though I have now spotted my mistake and resolved the issue. I'm not able to accept my own answer otherwise I would mark this resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have since solved this. I had not realised that live and test data were fully partitioned and it was necessary to create products separately in the test portal for the test api key to work.

On the off chance someone else encounters this issue, from the Stripe dashboard click the 'View test data' switch then follow the process to create products again.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst not resolving the OP's specific issue, I had the same symptoms and note the resolution in the hope it helps someone else.

From the Developers dashboard, I was set to use an old API version as we moved from one system to a newer one. I needed to update to use the latest API version to resolve the issue and get a fully populated /v1/products call.